# text color change inside a block but not outside

Tags: css

I watched a guy's video doing a parallax text effect see the image below and I'm trying to figure out how he did it. But it seems I can't understand his code (structure to get the the text inside the image in different color than the outside text)

Can someone please help me figure out how he did it?

This is his code: ([github code](https://github.com/codegridweb/Parallax-Overlay-Text-Effect-Using-Vanilla-Javascript))

[image]

Comment: He has multiple text for it. One inside the image container and one outside of it and uses Vanilla JS to move around. You just need to position them in different X positions, give them different color and then add `overflow: hidden` to the image container.

Comment: thanks a lot i just made a solution and it worked updating the post for anyone who need the code

Answer (score 1):

In the Code, you can see here the use of **transition** which is used for control animation speed when changing CSS properties ,in this changes occur when we scroll the web page and for that here javascript was used and here **title** is selected for performing action. Whenever the page will scrolls the javascript will execute the code and transition will occur when we scroll and we can see changes in text color i.e  color: rgb(255, 0, 0)  to rgb(255, 255, 255) & vice-versa in linear form animation.

Hope you got it !!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```js
let title = document.querySelectorAll('.title')
title.forEach( e => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll' , () => {
        e.style.transform = `translateX(` + window.scrollY / 20 + `%` + `)`;
    })
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #161616;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

main {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
 .img {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3b/65/c7/3b65c7f1236406596aa21349d7b7a4c6.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: red;
}
.title.title-dark {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
  top: 50%;
  left: 23.5%;
}
 .title {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="img">
            <div class="title title-dark">MEN STARVE FOR HONOR</div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">MEN STARVE FOR HONOR</div>

    </main>
</body>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

as per OP @Namlind's own prior edit to the question.